# Meaning of the Sentence Payable By

Tags: meaning

> The amount of Rs. 1000/- is payable by April 15, 2018.

The meaning here is the amount will be paid on April 15, 2018 or it will be paid within April 15 2018

Answer (score 1):

> payable **by** April 15, 2018.

means that it needs to be paid *on* or *before* April 15, 2018.

Comment: I disagree. By implies before. It may be that the payee is nice enough to accept it on the date, but there is no semantic or legal precedent to permit this.

Comment: @PaulChilds Please see [does notified by date include the end date](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/does-notified-by-date-include-the-end-date).  Maybe where you come from it is referred to as the **due date**.

Comment: so it is not exactly on April 15, 2018

Comment: Correct.  You could pay it on April 2, 2018 and the recipient would be happy.